# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_3\left [ x \right ]/\left \langle x^{2}+x+1 \right \rangle$ is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Show that $\mathbb{Z}_3\left [ x \right ]/\left \langle x^{2}+x+1 \right \rangle$ is not a field.

It suffice to show that the principal ideal $\left \langle x^{2}+x+1 \right \rangle$ is not a maximal ideal.

However, I am unable to get the ball rolling. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Over a field of characteristic $3$, $x^2+x+1=(x-1)^2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $1$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$, this polynomial is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ and therefore the ideal $\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ is not maximal.

Comment: How does irreducibility and maximal relates? I haven't came across this thought.

Comment: Since $x-1\mid x^2+x+1$, $\langle x^2+x+1\rangle\varsubsetneq\langle x-1\rangle$.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that in $\Bbb Z_3 [x]$ we have

$(x - 1)^2 = x^2 -2 x + 1 = x^2 + x + 1, \tag{1}$

since $-2x = x$ in $\Bbb Z_3 [x]$ .  (1) not only shows that $1 \in \Bbb Z_3$ is a zero of $x^2 + x + 1 \in \Bbb Z_3[x]$, but also that

$(x -  1)^2 = 0 \in \Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle; \tag{2}$

however,

$x - 1\ne 0 \in  \Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle, \tag{3}$

so we see that $ \Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$ contains non-zero nilpotent elements; not only is  $\Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$ not a field, it is not even an integral domain!

As a final note, if $x - 1$ *were* invertible in $\Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$, i.e. if we had $y \in \Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$ with

$(x - 1)y = 1, \tag{4}$

then

$x - 1 = (x - 1)(1) = (x - 1)((x - 1)y) = (x - 1)^2y = 0, \tag{5}$

clearly not the case for $x - 1 \in \Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Lord Shark the Unknown's comment (what a wonderful name btw), a field has the property that every nonzero element of the field has a multiplicative inverse.

i.e. $\forall p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_3\left [ x \right ]/\left \langle x^{2}+x+1 \right \rangle \backslash \{0\}, \exists p^{-1}(x): p(x)p^{-1}(x) = p^{-1}(x)p(x) = 1$

If you take the element $x-1$, you will recognize that there is no element that multiplies against $x-1$ to yield $1$. This can be exhaustively checked, or if you're clever, you can use a fact about zero divisors, to show that since $(x-1)^2 = 0$, there can't be a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Every non-zero element in a field has a unit.

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Comment: What then about the order of this field? How can it be deduced?

Comment: The order of the field is simply the number of elements in it. Since you are modding out by $\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$, you should realize that every polynomial in your field will be of degree 1 or 0. (What happens if a polynomial is of degree 2?). So your elements are as follows: $\{0,1,2,x,2x,x+1,x+2,2x+1,2x+2\}$. Therefore, the order is $9$.

Comment: An important question to consider: why isn't $x-1$ or $-2$ or any polynomial with a minus in this list?

Comment: Could you expand on the part where you used the fact about zero divisors?
A zero divisor $a$ is a non-zero element such that for a non-zero element $b$, $ab$=0. 
How is $(x-1)^{2}$ =0? I'm not quite following where you're coming from with this approach. I can see this is true for x=1. But what about other x element in $Z_{3}$?

Comment: $(x-1)^2 = x^2-2x+1 = x^2+x+1 = 0$. A zero divisor is essentially a nonzero element that multiplies against another nonzero element to yield zero. **A field has no zero divisors**. More specifically, if an element is a zero divisor, then it is not invertible.